# Google deployment manager reset manual changes

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I'm using GCE in my project. For infrastructure release I have used both terraform and puppet. Each of them have advantages and disadvantages. But both of them falls behind(with upgrading new functionality) compared with Google Deployment Manager and of course if I use only google(not multi-cloud) then it is the best solution for me to use native tools ). As puppet is a declarative tool, it allows anytime declare my infrastructure and any manual change should be reseted.

I am trying to write a script which will reset all manual changes that I made in my project. Of course manual changes is not the best practice, but sometimes it is the fastest way for hotfix (e.g changing the minimum count of instances in group for a critical moment).

Is there a way to perform the same functional in Google Deployment Manager.